# On editing Excel file using python, the changes are not reflecting until we open it

Tags: python, html, excel, flask

[Before opening the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T4xX.png)

[After opening the excel file and after the values appear in excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlfwR.png)

I need this because I need to use the output of this excel in some other calculations. How do I make it work pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just read the values of columns directly -

```
excelFile = "someFile.xlsx"

dataFrame = pd.read_excel(excelFile, sheet_name = "Sheet1", usecols="air_density_discrepancy")#read specific column

air_density_discrepancy = dataFrame.values
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but this would work if it's a brand new excel with the manual fed values. But in my case I have a file with just 3 columns. I use excel commands like 'vlookup, trim' to edit the existing file using python and add the output of these commands into a new column(ex. column trimID). After this editing is done, I save the workbook using workbook_obj.save(path), now when I try to read the contents it is NaN like in the above images. But when I open the excel once and on clicking one of the columns the values would appear, save it and close. Now when I read I get the values.